# Register for COM Interop

Tags: visual-studio-2008, permissions, com-interop

When the Register for COM Interop option in the build properties is checked, I get an error:

> Cannot register assembly -access
>   denied

When the option is unchecked, the project builds without any error. But my requirement is to register the COM objects as I need to use the same in VB. Can anyone help me out in this?

Answer (score 11):

Under Windows Vista and higher, try to run Visual Studio elevated, so it has the permissions necessary to perform a [regasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6.aspx) on your output assembly.

Answer (score 10):

An extension to Frédéric Hamidi's answer (upvote for your sir), you could either run Visual Studio as administrator, or turn off the 'register for COM interop', and open up a command prompt as the administrator.

The command to register the component is then something like this (on my machine - W7 64-bit):

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe /tlb /codebase C:\path\to\your\DLL
```

Personally I use the latter as the debugging process is quite complex and sometimes it's not possible to step through the code (or some of the debugging takes place on another machine)

Comment: Very useful. I am building an ancient Biztalk 2002 solution where RegisterForComInterop is set to true for most projects. I don't like running my build process an administrator so it was failing when it tried to RegAsm the compiled DLL. It looks like this is fine since I don't need it registered on the build server... we register the compiled DLL on the application server when deploying. Thanks!