# Problem with Register for COM interop - Error: Element not found

Tags: c#, com, interop

Using Visual Studio developing a dll that is a plug in for an app. The AddIn needs to be registered to work. Somehow something got messed up and I don't know what it was. At this point the dll will compile if I do not have "Build->Register for COM interop" checked. If it is checked then I get the error:

> The assembly "C:\Users\erics\source\repos\XXXX Tooling Utilities\XXXX Tooling Utilities\bin\Debug\XXXX Tooling Utilities.dll" could not be converted to a type library. Type library exporter encountered an error while processing 'XXXXUtilities.AddIn, XXXX Tooling Utilities'. Error: Element not found.  XXXX Tooling Utilities

I AM running visual studio as administrator as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996813/register-for-com-interop) points out.

I have tried registering this dll manually by using RegAsm.exe in Administrator mode but get a similar result:

> Types registered successfully
>   RegAsm : error RA0000 : Type library exporter encountered an error while processing 'XXXXUtilities.AddIn, XXXX Tooling Utilities'. Error: Element not found.

I also downloaded a [Dependency Walker](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) and looked at the dll with it. It looks to me like the dependency walker is finding all the dependencies OK.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you change versions of Excel since last time it worked?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was a missing dll:

> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll

I found this by building my project from scratch again. At each step I checked the app. I started having the issue when I installed a dependency from a NuGet package. The NuGet installation did not report anything wrong. The interop registration error message was much clearer this time telling me that one of the dll's that I just installed using NuGet had the issue. I opened the dll with the issue using the [Dependency Walker](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) and say that it could not find the above file.

To solve this I started with a Visual Studio repair and that seemed to restore the dll. Thankfully this fixed it. If It did not I was going to move on to repairing Windows 10.

Comment: That's not it, you wouldn't be able to start VS if this DLL were missing. Depends.exe is getting to be a very dangerous tool.

Comment: @HansPassant - You are saying that Depends is incorrect? I physically browsed to the folder and oleaut32.dll was not there. I definitely could still start Visual Studio. Do you have an idea of what it **could** be then?